# Running Awesomium on .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, awesomium

Does anybody know how I can run Awesomium.NET on .NET 3.5? Seems to only work on 4.0-4.5.1 right now.

According to [this question](http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/152/net-35-support.html), Awesomium 1.7 should be compatible with 3.5 by adding Awesomium.Mono to the project instead, but it seems like I'm not able to do that. When choosing 3.5 project in Visual Studio the Awesomium.Mono just disappears from the references list.

Answer (score 0):

Well when I started using **Awesomium** web browser at version **1.7.0** the reference dll are builded using **.net 4.0** version. You should try to look for an older version like **1.6.6** or **1.6.5** and check if they are builded using a older .net version. If you target your project to .net 4.0 you should not have any problem because at least windows XP with service pack 3 should have installed .net framework 4.0. But windows XP support has ended.

*A quick solution (but not the best) is to target the project to the .net 4.0 and export all dll references to the build path. That should make no problems when deploying the app to your clients machine because the exe will reference to the build path.*

Could you give me the reasons of why you are targeting .net 3.5 so I can understand a little more your issue with .net versions and try to think about another solution for you?